# PYOWM Оболочка Python для веб-API OpenWeatherMap

Tags: api, pyowm, openweathermap

При запуске кода выводится не температура в заданном городе, а статус облаков.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
from pyowm import OWM

owm = OWM('e4d6ef38905c895b034fc62d61ad5901')
city = 'Moscow'
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
location = mgr.weather_at_place(city)
weather = location.weather
print(weather)
```

или

```
from pyowm import OWM
# ---------- FREE API KEY examples ---------------------
owm = OWM('e4d6ef38905c895b034fc62d61ad5901')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
# Search for current weather in London (Great Britain) and get details
observation = mgr.weather_at_place('Moscow')
w = observation.weather
w.temperature('celsius')  # {'temp_max': 10.5, 'temp': 9.7, 'temp_min': 9.0}
print(w.temperature)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)